# What are best practices for Drupal QA? For example, how would you check for hard coded broken links?

Tags: web-development, drupal, code-quality, testing

Looking for suggestions on how to QA a Drupal website. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For verifying links are not dead and generating reports of bad links I would try the link checker module (http://drupal.org/project/linkchecker). I recently installed it. Admittedly you will probably need to do some configuring, but it would be a good place to start.